# These symbols are referring to? BOOK: Introduction to Genetic Algorithms by S.N.Sivanandam · S.N.Deepa

Tags: algorithms

I take this set of initialization (PAGE 120) from a genetic algorithm book with title: Introduction to Genetic Algorithms by S.N.Sivanandam & S.N.Deepa..here is the link http://www.mxea-lab.com/book/Int-Genetic-Algorithm-BOOK.pdf

unfortunately, the book is poor with explanation what the symbols are refering to..

My question, can some one give a simple explanation about this?

$Λ$
$x_1$ 
$u_1$
$w_1$
$u_x$
$x_x$
$w_x$ ?

since it is in the following set of
$Ω =$ {$(x_1,Λ, x_x )|u_1 ≤ x_1 ≤ w_1,Λ, u_x ≤ x_x ≤ w_x $}

Comment: Wow, that has got to be one of the worst-written books I've ever seen.  Literally every sentence on that page has some kind of grammatical error.  How on earth did that make it past the editorial board?

Comment: I totally agree with you @DanielMcLaury, some of the literature there are using different symbol each others, that actually should be connected since it is part of the one process. Any way any idea, how we can simplify the set of $Ω$? so I can easily know how its works? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like $\Lambda$ is a typographical encoding error (as Daniel McLaury points out, this is perhaps the least of the book's problems).  If you read $\Lambda$ as ellipsis, then we get

$$\Omega = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_x) \mid u_1\le x_1\le w_1, \ldots, u_x\le x_x\le w_x\}$$

which reads better aside from the horrid use of $x$ as a subscript for itself (shouldn't it be $n$?), and complete lack of sane definitions anywhere in the book.  Really, find yourself another book if at all possible.